# Undefined procedure when procedure is defined

Tags: prolog

I am trying to define a simple binary search tree. It is stored in lists like so: [Key, Left Tree, Right Tree]. 
I believe I have done this but when I try to use bstadd on an existing tree I get the following error.

```
?- bstadd(19,[],T1), bstadd(9, T1, T2).
ERROR: bstadd/3: Undefined procedure: right/3
   Exception: (8) right(9, [[], []], _G3233) ?
```

I have defined right with three arugments on line 8. What follows is my code:

```
% bstadd(Key, Tree, NewTree)
% add the element Key to the tree Tree and return an 
% new tree as NewTree. Element in the left subtree L must be less than Key and 
% elements in the right subtree R must be greater than Key.  This means duplicates 
% are not allowed in the binary search tree. Don’t put print statements in this 
% predicate.

right(Key, [TreeKey|TreeTail], [TreeKey|NewTree]) :- grabtail(KEY, TreeTail, NewTree]).
grabtail(KEY, [TreeKey|_], [TreeKey|NewTree]) :- bstadd(KEY, TreeKey, NewTree).
bstadd(KEY, [], [KEY,[],[]]).
bstadd(KEY, [TreeKey|TreeTail], [TreeKey|NewTree]) :- KEY > TreeKey, grabtail(KEY, TreeTail, NewTree).
bstadd(KEY, [TreeKey|TreeTail], [TreeKey|NewTree]) :- KEY < TreeKey, right(KEY, TreeTail, NewTree).


% inorder(Tree) 
% given a binary search tree Tree perform an inorder traversal of the 
% Tree printing (use print(X) ) the value of each vertex inorder.
inorder([TreeHead|TreeTail]) :- inright(TreeTail), print(TreeHead), intail(TreeTail).
inright([_|TreeTail]) :- intail(TreeTail).
intail([TreeHead|_]) :- inorder(TreeHead).
```

Any and all insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always look what the systems says while loading your file. I am sure there was some kind of syntax error. In your case, `right/3` contains a syntax error at the end. There is an unmatched closing `]`.

```
right(Key, [TreeKey|TreeTail], [TreeKey|NewTree]) :- grabtail(KEY, TreeTail, NewTree]).
                                                                                   ^^^
```

Comment: That was it. My prompt loads the file automatically and I had never noticed the syntax errors with the legal warnings. Thanks!

Comment: @stygma: Many Prolog systems do not stop on such errors but continue. Also watch out for "discontiguous" warnings and warnings about variables. In other programming languages the compiler would stop immediately. In Prolog, you have to watch out!